# Как сделать, чтобы содержимое не уезжало?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Хочу сделать слайдер, на котором поверх будет форма или любой другой текст.
Но при масштабировании в + 50-75%, а также при большом содержимом это содержимое уезжает за пределы. 
[image: картинка]

Как можно исправить ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoyvjp30/))?

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}




.overlay-startpage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);    
}

.overlay-startpage .carousel-item:nth-child(1) {
      background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSx-wyJux560QwH7cscODPxaAF9cvgk35PmksCMK_otVLtOU-aDw") no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    }

.overlay-startpage .carousel-item:nth-child(2) {
      background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSx-wyJux560QwH7cscODPxaAF9cvgk35PmksCMK_otVLtOU-aDw") no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;

}
.overlay-startpage .carousel-item:nth-child(3) {
  background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSx-wyJux560QwH7cscODPxaAF9cvgk35PmksCMK_otVLtOU-aDw") no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
background-position: center;
}

.bd-masthead {
    position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {

.bd-masthead {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
}

}
/* CAROUSELE STYLE */  


.carousel-indicators li {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 12px;
    border-top: unset;
    border-bottom: unset;
    height: 10px;
}


/* CAROUSELE STYLE */
```

```html
<main role="main" class="main">
      <div class="overlay-startpage carousel slide" >
    
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active" ></div>
          <div class="carousel-item" > </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" > </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="container-fluid">
          
          <div class="wrap">
              <div class="bd-masthead ">
                <div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur earum atque iste maiores at autem nesciunt deserunt, omnis tenetur error, unde ratione. Omnis atque, consectetur, fuga praesentium et accusamus? Id!</div>
                <div>Sapiente cupiditate similique beatae iste dicta pariatur neque eius facilis enim modi error odio repellat inventore, minus numquam, fuga velit! Ipsa deserunt praesentium, quasi voluptatum, sed blanditiis debitis accusamus pariatur!</div>
                <div>Dolorem, rem! Possimus rem nobis quibusdam illum officiis, commodi maiores minima earum fuga quod inventore autem eos molestias natus laborum nam perferendis sed neque incidunt id. Incidunt eaque molestias commodi!</div>
                <div>Facilis voluptatibus labore illum quidem vel adipisci minus molestiae, asperiores, ipsum quis id esse, possimus beatae ex ad soluta. Maxime perferendis odio aliquid iusto obcaecati recusandae harum quae adipisci laborum.</div>
                <div>Id eos, voluptate nemo rem. Aspernatur repellat, illum recusandae, voluptatum deserunt sunt. Corporis quas ut voluptate, nostrum incidunt quisquam, tempora recusandae, quasi dicta nobis aspernatur et amet! Necessitatibus, maxime, sit!</div></div>
              </div>

          </div>
       </div> 
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="carousel-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="carousel-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="carousel-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

не совсем точно выразились. Ничто никуда не уезжает. У вас форма спозиционирована абсолютно с фиксированной высотой равной высоте экрана. При меньших разрешениях - размера экрана мало для того, чтобы вместить текст. Нужно, чтобы высота формы была равна высоте контента, а не экрана.

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.overlay-startpage .carousel-item {
    height: 100%;

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #f0f;
}

.overlay-startpage .carousel-item {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.overlay-startpage .carousel-item:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTSx-wyJux560QwH7cscODPxaAF9cvgk35PmksCMK_otVLtOU-aDw");
}

.overlay-startpage .carousel-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("http://placeimg.com/500/300/an");
}

.overlay-startpage .carousel-item:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("http://placeimg.com/500/500/an");
}

.bd-masthead {
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .bd-masthead {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
  }
}


/* CAROUSELE STYLE */

.carousel-indicators li {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  border-top: unset;
  border-bottom: unset;
  height: 10px;
}


/* CAROUSELE STYLE */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .overlay-startpage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
</style>
<main role="main" class="main">
  <div class="overlay-startpage carousel slide">

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active"></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="bd-masthead ">
        <div class="form__content p-3">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" class="form__content__login form-control mb-2 o-color-blue" placeholder="Имя" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form__content__last-name form-control mb-2 o-color-blue" placeholder="Фамилия" required="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input class="form__content__your-mastery form-control mb-2" placeholder="Ваше искусство" required="">
              <div class="form__submenu form o-bckg-blue">
                <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center mb-0 p-3">

                  <ul class="form__submenu__list container d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-1" value="Актерское мастерство">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-1">Актерское мастерство</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-2" value="Режиссура">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-2">Режиссура</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-3" value="Монтаж">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-3">Монтаж</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center mb-0 p-3">

                  <ul class="form__submenu__list container d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-4" value="Вокал">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-4">Вокал</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-5" value="Инструменты">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-5">Инструменты</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-6" value="Битмейкинг">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-6">Битмейкинг</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center mb-0 p-3">

                  <ul class="form__submenu__list container d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap ">
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-7" value="Живопись">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-7">Живопись</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-8" value="Графика">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-8">Графика</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-9" value="Дизайн">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-9">Дизайн</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-10" value="Фотография">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-10">Фотография</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center mb-0 p-3">

                  <ul class="form__submenu__list container d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap ">
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-11" value="Проюссирование">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-11">Продюссирование</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item mr-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-12" value="Организиция">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-12">Организиция</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__submenu__item list-inline-item">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form__submenu__checkbox" id="form__submenu__item-13" value="HR">
                      <label class="form__submenu__label" for="form__submenu__item-13">HR</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="form__button">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-text form__submenu__icon o-btn-white col-2 "><i class="o-rotate-360 o-transition fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form__submenu__input__add col-10 p-3 text-center o-btn-white " placeholder="Введите свой вариант">
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-variable">
                    <div class="form-group  d-flex align-items-center mb-0 p-3">
                      <ul class="form__submenu__list user-variable__list container d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap ">
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form__content__middle-block pb-3 pt-3">
            <input type="text" class="form__content__email form-control o-color-blue" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form__content__phone form-control o-color-blue" placeholder="Телефон" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text" class="form__content__city form-control o-color-blue" placeholder="Город" required="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mb-0 mt-3">
            <input type="text" class="form__content__password form-control o-color-blue" placeholder="Пароль" required="">
            <input type="text" class="form__content__repassword form-control o-color-blue" placeholder="Подтвердите пароль" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="carousel-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="carousel-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="carousel-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
</main>
```

Comment: При уменьшении размера задний фон не на весь экран (( 
http://prntscr.com/mx2fym 
А должен быть по идее на весь

Comment: ну добавьте @media, чтобы при больших экранах высота слайдера 100vh, а при меньших в соответствии с контентом. Иначе, если очень хочется, чтобы и при маленьких экранах вмещалось - только контент уменьшать.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bd-masthead {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 3.8vh;
}
```

это называется viewport units

[Здесь](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/) подробнее написано про различные техники, чтобы текст не вылезал за пределы блока.

Comment: Однако это для текста. А, если форма есть? И она большая ( много полей для заполнения). Тогда что?)

Comment: Фишка в том, что при размерах ноута в 1366 пикселей уже начинает выходить вниз форма

Comment: форма - что имеется в виду? набор input, select, textarea? или текст в них? если текст, то мой совет тоже подойдет, а если сам элемент, то width: 100%

Comment: Да. много элементов. Напримиер вот такое https://jsfiddle.net/aoyvjp30/

Comment: Если форма длинная, то можно добавить ей  overflow-y:auto и задать фиксированную либо максимальную высоту

Comment: Не, это не самое удачное. Форма действительно длинная. Но слайдер то есть. Это будет странно добавлять скрол.. Надо как-то растянуть родителя